# Interface Builder adjusting navigation item incorrectly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

I have been messing with this for a while and I can't figure out what would be causing this issue. I have a UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController and on the generated UIViewController has two UINavigationItems:

1:left button is a default Done button with no image - appears fine
2:right button is a plain button with a 30x30 image

[image]

These buttons are not connected to any IBOutlet and are not altered within the Swift code. However when the code is compiled and is running on a simulator the right button is pushed down the screen. If the image is removed and standard text is added the button appears fine.

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Environment details:
MacOSX 10.11.2 , Xcode 7.2

Comment: Are you doing AutoLayout?

Comment: I am using Autolayout, however because this area is an auto generated area from having the embedded UINavigationController, no constraints can be applied to it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in objective-c to set the buttons to a specific side.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Notification.png"];
  UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
  [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self
                action:@selector(goToNotifiationView:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
  UIBarButtonItem *rightButton =
      [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

Comment: If this question is tagged [tag:swift], why would you answer in [tag:objective-c]?